# using javascript to double click one paragraph and all paragraphs changes

Tags: javascript, colors, paragraph

Let's say I have 5 paragraphs and if I double click one paragraph and all paragraphs changes color how can I do it with javascript?  I have to use javascript and nothing else.  Not even using jquery.

The code I have right now will only change that paragraph into blue not all....how can I do all if I double click any...

```
var allPara=document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(i=0;i<allPara.length;i++)
{
    allPara[i].ondblclick=function()
    {
    this.style.color="blue";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use CSS to help you.

You can use `getElementsByClassname` to select all the paragraphs (http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-getelementsbyclassname) after you change the classname for the selected paragraph.

Or, just do `getElementsByTagName` (h[ttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)) and change the classname (CSS) for the non-selected paragraphs, which will change the color.